# how to make a constructor for a fragment

Tags: android

I was just wondering how I could send parameters or arguments to a Fragment before it is created. Because I want to pass an array of strings to the fragment so that it could put all of them in the layout when it is created.  For example I am making a Leaderboard fragment, and my activitiy would pass in all of the scores etc. that the fragment would use to display.  I understand that I can use the Bundle and the .setArgs but will that work for my case?
Thank you

** EDIT **

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View singleplayerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleplayer_tab, container, false);
        String[] scores = (String[]) getArguments().get("scores");
        TextView tview = (TextView) singleplayerView.findViewById(R.id.player_name0);
        tview.setText(scores[0]);
        setupRank(singleplayerView);
        return singleplayerView;
    }

    public static SingleplayerTab newInstance(String[] scores) {
        SingleplayerTab spt = new SingleplayerTab();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putStringArray("scores", scores);
        spt.setArguments(args);
        return spt;
    }
```

CODE THAT CALLS IT

```
String[] scores = {"hello"};
Fragment singlePlayerFragment = SingleplayerTab.newInstance(scores);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that I can use the Bundle and the .setArgs but will that work for my case?

A `Bundle` can hold an `String[]` or an `ArrayList<String>`.

Moreover, this is the way you should do it, rather than a custom constructor. Android automatically recreates your fragments on a configuration change (e.g., screen rotation), and it will use your public zero-argument constructor for that. Hence, unless you use the arguments `Bundle`, or something else, you will lose your string array on a configuration change.

The recommended approach for this is to use a factory method, such as this one from an `EditorFragment`:

```
  static EditorFragment newInstance(int position) {
    EditorFragment frag=new EditorFragment();
    Bundle args=new Bundle();

    args.putInt(KEY_POSITION, position);
    frag.setArguments(args);

    return(frag);
  }
```

In this case, I want to pass `int position` into the fragment. I isolate packaging this into the `Bundle` into the factory method (`newInstance()`). When I need to create an instance of this fragment, I call `EditorFragment.newInstance()` instead of `new EditorFragment`, so I can supply the `position`. My fragment can get the `position` by reading the `KEY_POSITION` value out of the `getArguments()` `Bundle`. I use this approach in (among other places) [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Fragments), showing loading 10 of these editors into a `ViewPager`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So I guess my problem is that a fragment will call onCreateView once you make it by calling new Fragment() so can I send arguments to the fragment before or during that call?

Comment: @James: "So I guess my problem is that a fragment will call onCreateView once you make it by calling new Fragment()" -- no. `onCreateView()` will not be called until the fragment is attached to the activity and put into its container. That's why the factory method approach works -- you can put the `Bundle` into fragment well before `onCreateView()` is called.

Comment: I'm sorry to keep bothering you... but could you explain a little more about how to use the factory method?

Comment: Thanks for the code!! When I try to run it though I get a nullpointer because I expected that when you call the new SingleplayerTab in the newInstance method it would call onCreate which would try to get the arguments so I am a little bit stuck now... code is added in the edit